# Type mismatch error in filter excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

[Files Attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2L8rKqpaMWmb3FydTNiM2xidVE/view?usp=sharing)I have a list of text files which I'll import the data to new excel files in each tab accordance with the files imported. (say 20 text file = 20 tabs)
1. The first tab will delimited the data as per my requirement
2. Then it will filter as per the my 1st criteria and paste the data in a specified file.
3.It will again filter 2nd criteria and paste in the same way.
4. The first tab it will run correctly

Now I replicated for the rest of the tabs (Using while)however, the 1st criteria will run correctly but the 2nd criteria I'm getting the error as "Type Mismatch"
I have given a big space and comment where I'm getting error

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String
    Dim erow
    Dim IRow As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"
'Import multiple Text files
    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
'Only if none get selected
    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
'Create new tabs to generate one file with delimited
    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(47, 2), Array(72, 2), Array(93, 2), Array(103, 2)) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Cells.Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*$*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

'To pick the date
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*CHASE RETURN DATE*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(4).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            End With
            Selection.Copy
 Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 6), Cells(erow, 6))

'Sum Amount
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "=*$*", Operator:=xlAnd
            With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(3).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            End With
            Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 2), Cells(erow, 2))

'Create new tabs to generate rest of the files with delimited, filter, criteria as above
    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(47, 2), Array(72, 2), Array(93, 2), Array(103, 2)) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*$*", _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
'To pick the date
Workbooks(Worksheets(x)).Activate
        Selection.AutoFilter
```

'The below code I'm getting the error as Type mismatch

ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            "=*CHASE RETURN DATE*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

```
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using the `xlFilterValues` operator when you aren't using an array? Just remove it for a simple value filter.

Comment: Same error I'm getting :(

Comment: I forgot to add variable as wkbAll before the activation of worksheet. Sorry my mistake

    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add variable as wkbAll before the activation of worksheet. Sorry my mistake

```
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Which line is raising the error?  Do the following to find out:

Add a break point on the MsgBox line in  the error handler.

Add `resume` after `Resume ExitHandler`

Run the code.

When the code stops at the break point move the next statement to be "resume" and the start the code running by stepping over.

The line that raised the error will be selected.

This looks wrong:

```
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
```

You are pasting into the sheet using

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

but later int he same line you have

```
Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
```

this refers to the cells on the active sheet which is "Test.xlsm"  !

There are other lines in your code which have similar code .

VBA won't like this!

Let me know how you get on .

===========================================================

PART 2:

```
Destination:=Range("A1")
```

I suspect that Range needs to have a sheet reference added to it.

Similarly

```
Cells.select
```

When code has lines like the above that do not qualify the sheet that the cell or range is referring to, you must always consider what the active sheet is.

From your description, I don't fully understand what you want your code to do, but I suspect the above lines are causing problems as they look a bit suspicious.

Comment: I agree the way he is referencing is not correct but, the `.Paste` part is about the `Workbook` "Test.xlsm" and the `Worksheet` "Sheet1" thus your point about the `ActiveSheet` being "Test.xlsm" is not correct as its not a `Sheet` but a `Workbook`

Comment: I am wrong if `Sheets("Sheet1")` refers to the same sheet as `Sheet1`.  Sheet1 is a reference to the sheet with the codename of sheet1 in the workbook having the code.   So does the workbook "test.xlm" have the code is the question.  (It probably does and I am probably wrong, but just to be clear.)  I still want to know which line it is failing on, before I read the code again..

Comment: Please see part two, which may help more.

Comment: Correct the reference to the codename or "Sheet1" is confusing in the code. either way "erow" is an `Integer` and therefor wil not refer to anywhere else but just be an `Integer`. What would be better is if you explained that referencing to codename sheet1 and Sheets("Sheet1") is not correct. ;)

Comment: Thank you guys... I'll clarify this sheet issue. Test.xlsm where I have written the macro (Sheet:Master Sheet). In the same sheet I have Sheet1 where all the data which is copied need to be pasted. I have one more excel which will open once I run this macro where all the text file will be delimited accordance with the tab

Comment: This step it will activate the excel sheet which is auto generated and filter the data with different criteria. I'm getting the error in this code: Workbooks(Worksheets(x)).Activate
        Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*CHASE RETURN DATE*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: I stuck in this from past 2 days :(. Don't know

Comment: Those codes are fine... It's working. After that I selected the worksheet x to filter again with different criteria I'm getting this issue

Comment: Guys... I have attached the file. I think now @HarveyFrench it helps u guys... Let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: It sounds as if you are able to fix it.  Note that you have declared erow as a variant.  it will work like this, but if you do explicitly give it a data type use Long or LongLong (see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Please mark my answer as an answer as It sounds like it worked.